# ROS with SVO: Camera model not correctly specified

Tags: ros

I'm trying to get [rpg_svo](https://github.com/ros-perception/image_pipeline) - a project implementing semi-direct visual odometry - running. I can run the sample codes on a dataset, but not on a camera live stream.

I am using Indigo with the latest pull from the [image_pipeline](https://github.com/uzh-rpg/rpg_svohttps://github.com/uzh-rpg/rpg_svo%3C/p%3E). I hope the error is not because I am using Indigo and not a more stable version of ROS.

Here is my terminal dump:

```
SUMMARY
========

CLEAR PARAMETERS
 * /svo/

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro: indigo
 * /rosversion: 1.11.7
 * /svo/cam_topic: /usb_cam/image_raw
 * /svo/camera_matrix/cols: 3
 * /svo/camera_matrix/data: [423.946127, 0, 3...
 * /svo/camera_matrix/rows: 3
 * /svo/camera_name: narrow_stereo
 * /svo/distortion_coefficients/cols: 5
 * /svo/distortion_coefficients/data: [-0.395356, 0.132...
 * /svo/distortion_coefficients/rows: 1
 * /svo/distortion_model: plumb_bob
 * /svo/grid_size: 30
 * /svo/image_height: 480
 * /svo/image_width: 640
 * /svo/loba_num_iter: 0
 * /svo/max_n_kfs: 10
 * /svo/projection_matrix/cols: 4
 * /svo/projection_matrix/data: [312.081909, 0, 2...
 * /svo/projection_matrix/rows: 3
 * /svo/rectification_matrix/cols: 3
 * /svo/rectification_matrix/data: [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0...
 * /svo/rectification_matrix/rows: 3

NODES
  /
    svo (svo_ros/vo)

core service [/rosout] found
process[svo-1]: started with pid [14234]
create vo_node
[ WARN] [1406362716.365539658]: Cannot find value for parameter: svo/publish_img_pyr_level, assigning default: 0
[ WARN] [1406362716.367242172]: Cannot find value for parameter: svo/publish_every_nth_img, assigning default: 1
[ WARN] [1406362716.368814410]: Cannot find value for parameter: svo/publish_every_nth_dense_input, assigning default: 1
[ WARN] [1406362716.372849123]: Cannot find value for parameter: svo/publish_world_in_cam_frame, assigning default: 1
[ WARN] [1406362716.374322519]: Cannot find value for parameter: svo/publish_map_every_frame, assigning default: 0
[ WARN] [1406362716.375674323]: Cannot find value for parameter: svo/publish_point_display_time, assigning default: 0
[ WARN] [1406362716.685035733]: Cannot find value for parameter: svo/publish_markers, assigning default: 1
[ WARN] [1406362716.685835016]: Cannot find value for parameter: svo/publish_dense_input, assigning default: 0
[ WARN] [1406362716.686585599]: Cannot find value for parameter: svo/accept_console_user_input, assigning default: 1
[ERROR] [1406362716.687362055]: Cannot find value for parameter: svo/cam_model
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  Camera model not correctly specified.
[svo-1] process has died [pid 14234, exit code -6, cmd /home/long/Workspaces/catkin/devel/lib/svo_ros/vo __name:=svo __log:=/home/long/.ros/log/5b375c1a-149d-11e4-8bc0-24f5aa6f5f4f/svo-1.log].
log file: /home/long/.ros/log/5b375c1a-149d-11e4-8bc0-24f5aa6f5f4f/svo-1*.log
all processes on machine have died, roslaunch will exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done
```

This is my launchfile for usb_cam:

```
<launch>
    <node name="usb_cam" pkg="usb_cam" type="usb_cam_node" output="screen" >
        <param name="index" value="0"/>
        <param name="vendor" value="0x046d"/>
                <param name="product" value="0x080c"/>

        <param name="image_width" value="640" />
        <param name="image_height" value="480" />
        <param name="pixel_format" value="mjpeg" />
        <param name="camera_frame_id" value="webcam" />
    </node>
</launch>
```

And the launch file of svo_ros:

```
<launch>
    <node pkg="svo_ros" type="vo" name="svo" clear_params="true" output="screen">

        <!-- Camera topic to subscribe to -->
        <param name="cam_topic" value="/usb_cam/image_raw" type="str" />

        <!-- Camera calibration file -->
        <rosparam file="$(find svo_ros)/param/cam.yaml" />

        <!-- Default parameter settings: choose between vo_fast and vo_accurate -->
        <rosparam file="$(find svo_ros)/param/vo_fast.yaml" />

    </node>
</launch>
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your help! It wasn't the solution, but it gave me the right direction.

Indeed, there was something wrong with my .yaml calibration files. The thing is that the SVO library requires the calibration file in another format. To generate the calibration file, I used the cameracalibrator of the image_pipeline. Unfortunately, the library requires a calibration file in ATAN format. A tool to calibrate a monocular camera using this ATAN camera model, can be found here:

http://wiki.ros.org/ethzasl_ptam/Tutorials/camera_calibration

I hope, I can help other people who encounter the same problem!